# How to update child

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a component that references a child component like this

```
  cc: TheChildComponent;
  @ViewChild('theChildComponent') set details(content: TheChildComponent) {
           this.cc = content;
        };
```

TheChildComponent is a complicated component with several dom elements and an array of data that gets updated async through a rest call.

I would like to update my variable this.cc whenever I detect a change to the array of data in TheChildComponent.

I dont know how to do it though or if it is possible.

Comment: When you do the rest call, in the response, update the this.cc var, no?

Comment: I cant change the child component (where the rest call is) as it is a 3rd part component developed by a different team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be to emit the event in the child component whenever the child component changes its state. Given that you have no access to the child component implementation you have to look for more exotic solution.

I'd implement `ngDoCheck` lifecycle with combination of `@ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild(TheChildComponent) child: TheChildComponent;

ngDoCheck() {
  if (this.child && this.hasChanged(this.child.array))
    this.cc = this.child.array;
  }
}

private hasChanged(arr: any[]): boolean {
  // check if the child changed its state
}
```

Please keep in mind that this lifecycle hook is called very often, so keep your logic as thin as possible.

Check out [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ep9dtk).

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to get the new instance of TheChildComponent. The current one (i.e. this.cc) is stale and I need to update it with the new one. Is there a way to essentially running the setter set details again to refresh the childview reference?

Comment: It is not and will never be state. You do not need to new up a new instance. The current one is kept in sync by the angular framework.

Comment: @user2175783 check out my edit with a sample app. Child component asynchronously changes its array after a few seconds. The `ngDoCheck` hook with `@ViewChild` keeps the parent component in sync.

Comment: What I am observing is that the this.cc becomes stale (i.e. its array variable doesnt match the array of the child component that is being displayed).